# Finding the difference between "pwdLastSet" and current date/time

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Using PowerShell I am getting a count of all operating systems in Active Directory. I have the count of all Windows 10 OS, I now need a count of computers that have passwords greater than 90 days or older.

I've already tried scripts outside of the command using "Get-Date," however I need it incorporated into a single command if possible.

```bsh
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Computers,DC=DomainName,DC=com" -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "Windows 10*"} -Property , OperatingSystem, pwdLastSet, |
    select OperatingSystem, @{Name="pwdLastSet";Expression={([DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet))}}
```

Count: # of OS

"Older than 90 days": ?

Comment: I'm a little unsure as to what you want. What specific issues/errors are you currently getting? Do you mean you want a separate function to perform the operation?

Comment: I would like to avoid a separate function if possible. My issue is that I am new to PowerShell and don't know how to go about finding a solution for this. Is there a way to create a new column with the number of days from password-last-set to todays date. I am able to do it in excel using the formula "=DATEDIF(start_date,end_date,"d")" but I am trying to automate this process.

Comment: @zatch - part of your problem is "oh so leet!" coding. [*sigh ...*] DO NOT force everything into a one-liner just because "it is so **_leet_**!!!!!". break your pipeline into steps in a standard loop. then add the needed extra columns as you want, and finally output them to a CSV file or send them directly to excel with the `ImportExcel` module. ///// if you need to have things in a pipeline [to save RAM, usually]. you can then translate your easy-to-debug code into a pipeline with ease. [*grin*]

Comment: Add a filter to your search using (get-date) and the .AddDays() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we build off of what you have, then you can do the following:

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Computers,DC=DomainName,DC=com" -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "Windows 10*"} -Property , OperatingSystem, pwdLastSet, | Select-Object OperatingSystem, @{Name="pwdLastSet";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)}},@{Name="90_Days_Old";Expression={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)).AddDays(90) -le (Get-Date)}}
```

**Explanation:**

The `Select-Object` calculated property `90_Days_Old` will output `True` if the password is 90 days or older. Otherwise, `False` will output.
The key here is using the `.AddDays()` method from your DateTime object. You can choose to add 90 days to the `PwdLastSet` (`.AddDays(90)`) value or subtract 90 days from the current date and time (`.AddDays(-90)`).

---

This will not be the best way to approach this problem because of the following reasons:

- You should store reusable values in variables. This promotes neater code and reduces redundant code execution.
- `PwdLastSet` may not be the optimal property to check since it outputs in file time format. `PasswordLastSet` displays the date in human-readable format.

Answer (score 3):

The property `PwdLastSet` returns the literal value of the AD attribute `pwdLastSet`, which contains the timestamp encoded as filetime. You can decode that value to a `DateTime` value yourself via `[DateTime]::FromFileTime()`. However, PowerShell already does that for you and stores the decoded value in the property `PasswordLastSet`, so use that instead.

To get the password age of a computer you'd calculate the difference between the current date and `PasswordLastSet`, and then get the value of the `Days` property of the resuting `Timespan` object. Put that in a calculated property and you can filter for computers with a password age > 90 days.

```
$ou    = 'OU=Computers,DC=DomainName,DC=com'
$fltr  = 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows 10*"'
$props = 'OperatingSystem', 'PasswordLastSet'

$cutoff = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-90)

$hosts = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $ou -Filter $fltr -Property $props |
         Select-Object OperatingSystem,
             @{n='PasswordAge';e={((Get-Date) - $_.PasswordLastSet).Days}}

($hosts | Where-Object { $_.PasswordAge -gt 90 }).Count
```

Comment: Maybe I read the question wrong, but I thought the OP wanted the total machine count _and_ the number older than 90 days - he'd only get the latter doing this.

Comment: This is an example of the output I have at the moment. Just need an extra column that has an output of what the number of days are. in this case it is (7) because the password was last set 7 days ago.                                                                                                   OperatingSystem pwdLastSet
--------------- ----------
Windows 10 Pro  8/22/2019 11:07:16 AM

Comment: @zatch Adjusted answer accordingly.